# Problem parsing large json using eval and alternative

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, eval, onreadystatechange

I'm trying to parse a large json file (240'000 chars) using javascript. I'm using ajax to retrieve json data from a servlet. The code I'm using works fine with smaller samples but just throws this out when xmlHttp.responseText contains a lot of json data.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL 
mycallbackFunction
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange
```

It says that the unexpected token is on the line containing

```
var data = eval('(' + xmlHttp.responseText + ')');
```

This is the gist of the code:

```
getJsonData(mycallbackFunction, parameters);

function getJsonData(callbackFunction, parameters){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.open('GET', servlet_url + parameters, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        callbackFunction(xmlHttp);
    }
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function mycallbackFunction(xmlHttp){
    var data = eval('(' + xmlHttp.responseText + ')');
}
```

The method that uses eval() is called from xmlHttp.onreadystatechange if that makes any difference.

I also tried using json2.js and a get the same result, it works fine with smaller json samples but when I try with my 240k chars file it says:

```
Uncaught #<Object>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the browser's native JSON parsing capabilities instead of `eval()`?

Comment: won't be the size that's the issue - you've got malformed JSON in there somewhere.

Comment: @BonyT makes a good point. Does the JSON validate in http://jsonlint.com? (If it can deal with 240k of data)

Comment: jsonlint is really savior but it can't handle 240k data. How do I use the native JSON parser? can't even seem to google it, now I know I'm tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
var data = JSON.parse( xmlHttp.responseText );
```

To ensure a JSON parser is available in browsers which do not provide one (*cough* IE *cough*), you should include Douglas Crockford's [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) on your page ahead of other scripts.

If the parser errors on your data, you should validate the JSON for problems via something like http://jsonlint.com/ . If you need, you should break your data down into smaller chunks for the validation site.

Also, to be sure your JSON is valid, you should be using a proper JSON serialization method at the server, rather than "manually" outputting via echos, prints, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem was not with the parsing but with erroneous data. I'll create another question for it.